# How to disable entity creation with JPA to map views?

Tags: java, jpa, view, orm

I would like to map view with JPA entity. Obviously, it should not attempt to create a table with the name of entity, because it will map a view, created elsewhere.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

DDL generation must be turned on in JPA so just don't turn it on, but it is an all or nothing for all entities within the persistence unit. Options to get around it if you need it for some but not all entities is

1. have 2 persistence units. 1 of the persistence units include everything and be used by your code, while the other just include a subset of entities you need table creation for.
2. Generate scripts and use JPA to execute them. You can then manually remove table creation entries for those that already have views - see https://thorben-janssen.com/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/
3. some combination of the options. We use different persistence units for build time operations that are only for the build process. You could use secondary persistence units (entirely separate persistence.xml) to build the scripts to include with the project.